# RSpec mocking all methods on object

Tags: rspec, mocking

I am working on some rspec tests now where one of my initialize parameters is a "foreign" class, meaning I have no clue where it comes from. It is injected from a framework I am using. In my code I need to utilize this object for various things, mostly/exclusively to call methods to pass data to this object (no data extraction).

Is it possible to completely mock an object so that I can verify that certain, undefined, methods are called.

```
#an example of what this object could look like
let(:my_obscure_object) { RSpec.complete_mock } #NOTE: This does not work
...
it "verify .whatever method is called" do
  expect(my_obscure_object).to receive(:whatever).with(some_data)
  my_class.work
end

it "verify .sub_whatever method is called" do
  expect(my_obscure_object.sub_thing).to receive(:sub_whatever).with(some_data)
  my_class.work2
end
```

The method I can think of currently to solve this is to make an object and stub every single possible method I might need, like this

```
#an example of a tedious method to solve my problem
let(:my_obscure_object) { Object.new }
before(:each) do
  my_obscure_object.stub(:whatever) { nil }
  my_obscure_object.stub(:whatever2) { nil }
  my_obscure_object.stub(:whatever3) { nil }
  my_obscure_object.stub(:whatever4) { nil }
  my_obscure_object.stub(:whatever5) { nil }
  ob = Object.new
  ob.stub(:sub_whatever) { nil }
  my_obscure_object.stub(:sub_thing) { ob }
end
...
it "verify .whatever method is called" do
  expect(my_obscure_object).to receive(:whatever).with(some_data)
  my_class.work
end
it "verify .sub_whatever method is called" do
  expect(my_obscure_object.sub_thing).to receive(:sub_whatever).with(some_data)
  my_class.work2
end
```

Is there any solutions to my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a test double which will accept all method calls using `as_null_object`, as follows:

```
describe "SO example" do
  #an example of what this object could look like
  let(:my_obscure_object) { double("obscure").as_null_object }
  let(:some_data) { 'foobar'}

  it "verify .whatever method is called" do
    expect(my_obscure_object).to receive(:whatever).with(some_data)
    my_obscure_object.whatever(some_data)
  end

  it "verify .sub_whatever method is called" do
    expect(my_obscure_object).to receive_message_chain(:whatever, :sub_whatever)
    my_obscure_object.whatever.sub_whatever
  end

end
```

Note that the `receive_message_chain` method is only available as of RSpec 3.0.0.beta2 available from github and does not allow you to specify any expected argument values. You can rewrite that expectation using individual test doubles if you want to use an older version of RSpec or specify the arguments passed.

Comment: Will "obscure" be the class? Struggling to find the meaning of the string input to the double method.

Comment: No. The first argument to `double` is just a handle that can be used for debugging purposes. It's ignored from the standpoint of RSpec's functionality.

Comment: Just found it in the doc. The string is just an identifier. [See doc](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs)